# Select Min value of a RavenDB field over a set of documents

Tags: linq, lucene, nosql, ravendb, min

How can I find the Min value of a RavenDB document property over all documents that satisfy a condition.

For example, I want to find what is the earliest release date of all movie documents in the ravendb database that belong NY state.

I wrote something like this.. please correct me.. I need help at "??????" in the following query...

```
  DateTime EarliestDate = session.Query<Movie>()                      
                         .Where(x => x.State == "NY")
                         .GroupBy(x => x.ReleaseDate)
                         .Select????Min(x => x.ReleaseDate));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may be wrong, but don't you just want this:

```
DateTime EarliestDate = session.Query<Movie>()                      
                         .Where(x => x.State == "NY")
                         .Min(x => x.ReleaseDate);
```

**UPDATE:**
try this

```
DateTime EarliestDate = session.Query<Movie>()                      
                             .Where(x => x.State == "NY")
                             .OrderBy(x => x.ReleaseDate)
                             .Take(1)
                             .Select(x => x.ReleaseDate)
                             .FirstOrDefault();
```